# プログラミング（javaのクラス)について質問があります。

Tags: java

独習にのっているコードどおりに記述したはずなのですが実行できません。
コードは

```
class Circle{
    double x;
    double y;
    double radius;

    Circle(double x){
        this (x, 0, 1);
    }
    Circle(double x, double y){
        this(x, y, 1);
    }
    Circle(double x , double y, double radius){
        this.x      = x;
        this.y      = y;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}
class CircleThis{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Circle c = new Circle(1.1, 3.4 , 10);
        System.out.println("c.x      = " + c.x);
        System.out.println("c.y      = " + c.y);
        System.out.println("c.radius = " + c.radius);
    }
}
```

実行したら
エラー：メイン・メソッドがクラスCircleでみつかりません。次のようにメイン・メソッドを定義してください。
    public static void main(String[] args)
またはJavaFXアプリケーション・クラスはjavafx.application.Applicationを拡張する必要があります。
とでます。
本ではこのとおりに乗っているのですがなにがいけないのでしょうか。
よければこういった問題点を理解するのに足りていない知識も踏まえて教えていただけると
幸いです。
よろしくおねがいいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ソースを記述したファイルが`Circle.java`で次のようにコンパイルしたとすると、
`javac Circle.java`
同じフォルダに`Circle.class`と`CircleThis.class`ができているはずです。
エラーメッセージは
`java Circle`
のように実行しようとしているためで、
`main`が存在するのは、`CircleThis` クラスの方ですから
`java CircleThis`
のように実行します。

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございました！
やってみたらできました。mainがあるクラスを打ち込んで実行しないといけないのですね。
色々ありがとうございました。またよろしければお願い致します。

Comment: そうです、実行する時に大本としてmainを呼び出してプログラムの実行を開始しようとします。Circleの方には実行しようとしてもmainがないのでそのことをお説教されたというわけです。

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございました。